# I will create a master Windows 7 Ultimate Edition image, but there are missing object blocks while configuring answer file. How can i find it?

Tags: windows-7, configuration, waik, answer-file

I will create a master Windows 7 image, but there are missing object blocks while configuring answer file. **Is it about windows7 Ultimate? I thought like that because blogs includes explanation about windows7 Enterprise**

For example:

1 Windows PE 
(add nothing to this block)

2. Offline Servicing 
   (add nothing to this block)

3.Generalize 
Add object block:

**amd64_Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP_6.1.7600.16385_neutral(missing)**

4. specialize 
   Add object blocks:

amd64_Microsoft-Windows-Deployment_6.1.7600.16385_neutral

**amd64_Microsoft-Windows-Security SPP-UX_6.1.7600.16385_neutral(missing)**

**amd64_Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup_6.1.7600.16385_neutral(missing)**

5. auditSystem 
   (add nothing to this block)
6. audituser 
   (add nothing to this block)
7. oobeSystem 
   Add object blocks:

**amd64_Microsoft-Windows-International-Core_6.1.7600.16385_neutral (missing)
amd64_Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup_6.1.7600.16385_neutral(missing)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is solved. This is relationship with SP1. 
For example:

no SP1: "amd64_Microsoft-Windows-International-Core_**6.1.7600.16385**_neutraL"

SP1 exists: amd64_Microsoft-Windows-International-Core_**6.1.7601.17514**_neutral"

As you can see the version is not the same.